# How to emulate --data-binary @dummy.json using java

Tags: java, file, curl, binary

I wanted to use use following curl command from java.

curl -XPOST 'http://some_url' --data-binary @dummy.json

I am not sure how to pass in --data-binary @dummy.json. I tried following but it's not the right way....

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(POSTUrl);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("-d", new FileBody(jsonFile));
```